# jQuery CSS animations with addClass and removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-animations, animate.css

So, I have now made jQuery Ajax code that checks that the username and password are correct. But instead of just displaying a error message, I'd like to shake the element as well.

### Define Shake?

That kind of shake that wordpress has. Go to wordpress.com/wp-login.php and fill there some random info and the element shakes.

That shake can be done by [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

### What's the problem then?

When the login fails, jQuery makes this.

`$('.element').addClass('shake');`

But because the shake element has CSS Animations that run only once, we won't be needing the CSS shake class after it shaked the element.

So I tried:

`$('.element').addClass('shake').removeClass('shake');`

But that happens all too quickly.

So I tried again:

`$('.element').addClass('shake').delay(1000).removeClass('shake');`

Still not play the animation and then remove the class `.shake` from the `.element`. If the user enters wrong details more then once then shake won't work.

You can play with the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A8K3w/2/).

Goal is to be able to shake the element more then once by clicking the Shake button.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the following to remove the class when the animation completes.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VrZM8/)

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        el = $('.element');
        el.addClass('shake');
        el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            el.removeClass('shake');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That actually works! But I have no clue how it works since I don't really know much JS

Comment: I guess I have to look more into .one()

Comment: Daaamn I've been looking for this solution all over the place!! Been trying some hacks adding and removing the animation attribute but no luck. Now with this worked like a charm!!! thumbs up! Thank you

Comment: @Cʜᴜɴ - Awesome, that's good to know! I'm glad these answers are helping so many people.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the shake class, add a small time out and then add the shake class. That will make it shake every time:

```
$(function(){
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.element').removeClass('shake');
    setTimeout(function(){
          $('.element').addClass('shake');
    }, 50);
});
```

});

Comment: This works, but it produces a weird flicker for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/VYuec/ (Chrome)

Comment: I can't reproduce the flickering here, but I would suggest: Let it shake first, have the time out afterwards and remove the class after the time out. That should avoid flickering.

Answer (score 1):

`addClass()` and `removeClass()` don't respect `delay()`, so they'll ignore the delay and just do what they were told to like the `delay()` doesn't exist

`fadeIn()` does though.

So if you do this, it should work correctly. This calls the anonymous function to remove class shake after delay and fadeIn have finished.

```
$('.element').addClass('shake').delay(1000).fadeIn(0, function() { $(this).removeClass('shake'); });
```

Comment: There is no need for the element to fadeOut

Comment: It looks like @Stilly.stack used .fadeOut in order for `.delay` to work, otherwise `.delay` won't run (only runs against animations and not add/remove class)

Comment: I mean that now when http://jsfiddle.net/A8K3w/3/ you hit Shake, it disappears after the animation is completed.